# How to make a ECharts Graph zoom out to show the full graph?

Tags: echarts

in this [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=graphgl-gpu-layout&gl=1&theme=dark&code=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQOTgEzQGcAKAdxnygAsBhOcKAGkWrRgHNqp7GBKRAG8AUIkQA3DCkRgCxRAF5EAbQC6AblGJgcaSUnSYixAAZ1iIwB5EFKnQZgo5mAGoXAkWLE69BxACtjMwDEazZObl5Hc383Dy0vGTkiADoABxAiahJPRK8AenzEAA8ALkQAWSxqFJQMMHw4AFsSAQAqGxgGuDIUrrA0FAB1ShpEDoBGEyYEvMLEAE9yqppa-saW9s7u3v7BgAl2LihxxCmZvMTJABsQNGXqte7N2bEAXz5NRLetH7F0KAgFBIWSEIiaH6gSCwBDIdBYNAAUXwHGI5FG9kYLHCxyiUHiYj8aBR8iUai-2l0iH0UgsQWcoU6djxzjiQlmPmpfkCSmCgTCR0iDicATZuUSMGA1KsTJoeMQAFozgTLohiajUhksjlXnkiAwUBB7nSXCEOrY5cKLqqxFApKioOUjKaJohTYFzRi8dabTc7uUJrr3p9dX88pLqfzWIKeMLFcr2Tb1cR0plsuLVfqgUanW6zbLMY4faq7SgHbnTSRAi6thbC8wg14_cbAzaPhTvrMw2GAUCkMnwcIfn5QaS4ZhsHgwSQptMziYTCGiSSiMZUBOkSuZwuWLOQ3A0jCkEpckRBjBiOVlLMM2IiBAMNc0AAZGBNGCOoSId9gcomFILoBC4TCwTQYGU84mIgbzFmIABecDNH-KQgbqUALGkxoAOQcHUaTUAA4s-WGwUkYLlKORCkQO5QDqRH5oE0ADK6FPuUt5eBAcDXLo5RYWWABGGAkAATAArGJTDiZJ0lMP-AAcfBYaGpHXF0aAsQsbGJqqXE8SgfGCcJskmRJckpIpJGNnW5QAMwqbqPhGgAglA1wYEQInsY2RDYGkRDlJJjb-B-2AoAAKtxgxoJALbTI2yZDDGACSYDALcMU5qYAGtnkYbvFoqhDuoQA) you see the the intial zoom of the series set to 0.1.

But the graph is not rendered in the center of the viewport.

How do I accomplish that?